# kotlin project can't be build in gradle(can not find reference)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build, kotlin

I have a java project that write in kotlin ,i use intelliJ IDEA to develop this project. I have trouble on the dependencies setting (multiple project). I already read lot of examples , but I can't find the workaround , here is my dependencies setting code, it can be build in java class correctly , but the kotlin class will get lot of error 'Unresolved reference' . Is that any wrong about my setting or gradle is not suitable with kotlin .

PS : when i only build core project , build process will successful , but build at test project will get the reference unresolved error

following is the code of build.gradle.

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'
    group 'TestProject'
    version '1.0'}
subprojects{
    apply plugin:  'java'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'
    def defaultEncoding = 'UTF-8'
    compileJava.options.encoding = defaultEncoding
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()}

    dependencies {
        // Kotlin
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
        // JDOM
        compile "org.jdom:jdom:$jdom_version"
        // Jaxen
        compile group: 'jaxen', name: 'jaxen', version: '1.1.6'
        // JUnit
        compile "junit:junit:$junit_version"
        // Log4j2
        compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.5"
        compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.5"
        // JOGL
        String[] versions = "$jogl_version".split("\\.")
        if (Integer.parseInt(versions[0]) >= 2 &&  Integer.parseInt(versions[1]) >= 2) {  
            compile "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:$jogl_version"
            compile "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:$jogl_version"
            println "JOGL 2.2.0 later"
        } else {      
            compile files("../libs/thirdparty/jogl/jogl-2/jar/jogl-all.jar")
            compile files("../libs/thirdparty/jogl/jogl-2/jar/gluegen-rt.jar")
            println "JOGL 2.1.5 before"}
        runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:$jogl_version:natives-linux-amd64"
        runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:$jogl_version:natives-linux-i586"
        runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:$jogl_version:natives-macosx-universal"
        runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:$jogl_version:natives-windows-amd64"
        runtime "org.jogamp.gluegen:gluegen-rt:$jogl_version:natives-windows-i586"
        runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:$jogl_version:natives-linux-amd64"
        runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:$jogl_version:natives-linux-i586"
        runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:$jogl_version:natives-macosx-universal"
        runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:$jogl_version:natives-windows-amd64"
        runtime "org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:$jogl_version:natives-windows-i586"

        testCompile "junit:junit:$junit_version"
        testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"

        // Jython
        compile 'org.python:jython-standalone:2.7.0'
        // RxKotlin
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxkotlin:0.55.0'
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxswing:0.24.0'
        // Mockito
        compile 'org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.5'  
        compile 'args4j:args4j:2.33'

        compile 'org.json:json:20160212'
        // Lombok
        compile "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombok_version"}

    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']

    sourceSets.main.kotlin.srcDirs = ['src']

    sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ['../res','src']

    sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs = ['test']

    sourceSets.test.kotlin.srcDirs = ['test']

    sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs = ['../res','src']

    buildDir = 'build'}

buildscript {
    // JOGL 
    ext.jogl_version = '2.1.0'

    // Kotlin 
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.1'

    // JUnit 
    ext.junit_version = '4.12'

    // JDOM 
    ext.jdom_version = '1.1'

    // Lombok 
    ext.lombok_version ='1.16.8'

    repositories {
        flatDir { dirs "lib" }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()}
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"}}

dependencies {
    buildDir = 'out'}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

project(':mainproject') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
        compile project(':movie')}}

project(':movie'){
    dependencies{
        compile project(':core')}}
```

Comment: What problem are you getting with posting code in a correct format? You should be able to paste in your code into the text field, select it all and just choose "Code sample" button at the top of the text field. The icon looks like this: `{}`. Or you can hit Ctrl+K after selecting text.

Comment: thank you, ctrl+K is work, if i use icon it can't be contain in correctly format.

Comment: There is a current issue with Gradle + Kotlin and the daemon, you will find that it references an old version of a class instead of a new.  So you receive unresolved references in this case.  Try `./gradlew --stop` to stop the daemon, then do a clean build and see if it fixes the problem.  or `./gradlew --no-daemon` when building to check.